# Office.js Excel Add-In Dialog Prompts to open in new window even though Dialog host is same as function file host

Tags: ms-office, office-js

From my manifest.xml

```
            <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/excel-refresh" />
```

From my function file

```
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:4000/excel-dialog?action=loading', {height:50, width:50}, dialogCallback)
```

Instead of loading my page in Excel Online itself, the add-in prompts me to open it in a new tab. After clicking Allow, my html page does load in a new tab. I am using the same host and port so this should not be happening.

[Screenshot of generic popup that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVpaK.png)

Comment: displayDialogAsync should open the resource excel-dialog in a popup. Are you saying that that does not happen? Is excel-dialog an html page?

Comment: excel-dialog is an html page. What happens is I get a generic popup prompting me to open excel-dialog in a new tab. Updated question for clarity

Comment: @RickKirkham any idea what could be wrong? and what's with the downvote?

Comment: (I'm not the one who down voted the question.) Does it change anything if you remove the query parameter from the call of displayDialogAsync? Also, if you just type 'https://localhost:4000/excel-dialog?action=loading' into a browser (when the add-in is running) does it open right away or do you get the strange prompt? If you run the add-in in desktop Excel (Click-to-Run), does it work there? Finally, could you see if you get different results if you add displayInIframe: true to the options object you pass to displayDialogAsync.

Comment: @RickKirkham yup that displayInFrame flag was what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments under the OP's question, the solution is to pass and Options object to the call of `displayDialogAsync` that sets `displayInIframe` to true. Example:

```
displayDialogAsync("https://myDomain/myPage.html", {height:50, width:50, displayInIframe: true}, dialogCallback);
```